# Configuring own node on Temple wallet: `Invalid RPC: Cannot get chain id`

Tags: node, rpc, temple

I've set up a full mainnet node on a VPS. The RPC port of the node (8733) is not exposed to the Internet, but I can access it from my local machine via an SSH port forward:

`ssh remote-note -L8733:localhost:8732`

Accessing `http://localhost:8733` works well from my local machine, both using `tezos-client` as well as accessing the RPC endpoints from a web browser.

However when I try to configure a Temple wallet on the same machine to use the same node URL, it gives me an error:

`Invalid RPC: Cannot get chain id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening a "Maximised View" of Temple and enabling the developer console, I could see CORS errors when I tried to add the node to Temple.

The CORS issue was fixed by stopping and restarting `tezos-node` with these additional flags:

`--cors-header='content-type' --cors-origin='*'`

I was then able to successfully add and use my own node with the Temple wallet.

Comment: Thanks to the folks from the Madfish | Developers Community Telegram channel for helping me troubleshoot this.